# Is there any reason why the stream cout has the flag std::ios_base::skipws set?

Tags: c++, iostream

`cout` has the flags `std::ios_base::skipws` and `std::ios_base::dec` set by default

You can verify this with the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::fmtflags flags = cout.flags();
    string sflags;

    if( flags & ios_base::skipws ) sflags += "skipws";
    if( flags & ios_base::unitbuf ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "unitbuf" : " unitbuf";
    if( flags & ios_base::uppercase ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "uppercase" : " uppercase";
    if( flags & ios_base::showbase ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "showbase" : " showbase";
    if( flags & ios_base::showpoint ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "showpoint" : " showpoint";
    if( flags & ios_base::showpos ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "showpos" : " showpos";
    if( flags & ios_base::left ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "left" : " left";
    if( flags & ios_base::right ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "right" : " right";
    if( flags & ios_base::internal ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "internal" : " internal";
    if( flags & ios_base::dec ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "dec" : " dec";
    if( flags & ios_base::oct ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "oct" : " oct";
    if( flags & ios_base::hex ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "hex" : " hex";
    if( flags & ios_base::scientific ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "scientific" : " scientific";
    if( flags & ios_base::fixed ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "fixed" : " fixed";
    if( flags & ios_base::hexfloat ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "hexfloat" : " hexfloat";
    if( flags & ios_base::boolalpha ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "boolalpha" : " boolalpha";
    if( flags & ios_base::_Stdio ) sflags += sflags.empty() ? "_Stdio" : " _Stdio";

    cout << "Standard flags from cout stream: " << sflags << endl;
}
```

Clearly the flag `std::ios_base::skipws` is irrelevant for cout.

Comment: If it's irrelevant, what difference does it make whether it's set or not set? It has to have some value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flags and their default setting is inherited from `std::ios_base` (well, actually, the settings are defined for `std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>`; the defaults are define in 27.5.5.2 [basic.ios.cons]), a common base class of both input and output streams. The flags are shared if the stream inherits from both input and output streams. There are other flags which don't make much sense on either input or output streams.

Answer (score 1):

The `skipws` flag is set in *all* standard streams on initialization. Not just `std::cout`. It makes as much sense for `std::cout` as for any other stream. You can disable it with `noskipws` if you hate it so much.